# JQuery Mobile theming list with blocks in one line

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have been trying to theme the following [link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/DAJca/ with no success, here is an example of one item:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-li">
                    <div>
                        <label class="ui-label" for="0">Afghan</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right">
                        <select name="0" id="0" onchange="saveSelect(this,'Food',0);" data-role="slider"
                        data-mini="true">
                            <option value="0">No</option>
                            <option value="1" undefined>Yes</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul>
```

I want the label to be on the left and the slider on the right, align to each other with a nice "list item" background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pzfr2/

CSS used:

```
#slider-container {
    position: relative;
    float:right;  
    margin-top: -10px !important;    
}

#slider-container .ui-slider {
    margin-top: -50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, just though JQuery would have had something like that in their CSS.